# icCube usage from Libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice, xmla, iccube

http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/integration/integration.php

This works in excel, but being a mac user I would prefer it works in Libreoffice. I have no plans of installing Mac Excel also.

Is there any tool in libreoffice to do this?

I have tried Palo plugin but xmla connection does not work. Is the palo plugin not usable?

Answer (score 1):

First time I hear about this plugin, it would be worth contacting the team behind the Palo plugin as icCube is a standard XMLA server. Hopefully they are not using Palo specific features.

If you can send an export of the logs ( Monitoring / Runtime / Log Files ) to support at iccube we can have a look.